# Using bower on Openshift Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, openshift, bower

How to configure deploy file to run bower install on laravel project.

npm install from the app-root directory didn't work.

Comment: Define "didn't work".

Comment: It dont work while you import it or what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Bower depends mainly on node and npm, are you sure u have them installed? because npm install should do the initial trick